# How can I navigate to a certain Pivot page in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, pivotviewer

I have created a MainPage with two links. Both will take the user to a new Pivot page.
However, the first link will open the first page of the Pivot, while the second will open the second page of the Pivot.

I have the following code so far:

MainPage:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PivotTester.xaml?goto=" + i, UriKind.Relative));
```

and then on PivotTester page:

```
namespace CelticNow
{
public partial class PivotTester : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    PivotTester pivot = new PivotTester();

    public PivotTester()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string strItemIndex;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("goto", out strItemIndex))
            pivot.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(strItemIndex);

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}
}
```

I added in the "Pivot pivot = new..." as using PivotTester.SelectedIndex wouldn't work.

Can anyone provide a solution as to how I would make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Because you have created a new instance, what you have to do is to set Name property to your Pivot control that you use in the design, that set SelectedIndex

Comment: thanks, but I keep getting an error on the "SelectedItem" - "PivotTester doesn't contain a definition for" it. any ideas?

Comment: notice that pivottester is your current page (:

Comment: you need to set SelectedIndex to the pivot control

Comment: sorry - im still lost here. how do I that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you, Remove below line of code from your code

```
//Remove if not necessary
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
   string strItemIndex;
    if(NavigationContext.QueryString.Contains("goto"))
    {
      strItemIndex=NavigationContext.QueryString["goto"].ToString();
      pivotControl.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(strItemIndex);
    }

   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
  }
```

**EDIT**

Make changes in your xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <!--Pivot Control-->
            <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="pivotControl">
                <!--Pivot item one-->
                <controls:PivotItem Header="one">
                    <Grid/>
                </controls:PivotItem>
                <!--Pivot item two-->
                <controls:PivotItem Header="two">
                    <Grid/>
                </controls:PivotItem>
            </controls:Pivot>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: @user3176804 are you using pivot control or anything else ??

Comment: I'm got my MainPage which is also a Pivot (MainPage.xaml) and PivotTester.xaml - that's all

Comment: @user3176804 Could you share xaml. may that gives better idea how can we help you.

Comment: `code`
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <controls:PivotItem Header="one">
                <Grid/>
            </controls:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <controls:PivotItem Header="two">
                <Grid/>
            </controls:PivotItem>
        </controls:Pivot>
    </Grid>
`code`

Comment: @user3176804 i made changes in my ans. Please check it, i am sure it helps you. Remove PivotTester pivot = new PivotTester();
it seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code: `pivot.SelectedItem = x:Name of the pivot item`. Working good.

Comment: thanks, but I keep getting an error on the "SelectedItem" - "PivotTester doesn't contain a definition for" it. any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any PivotItems added?

Comment: yeah, I have two pivot items.